# Deriving the solution for ridge polynomial regression.

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, statistical-inference, machine-learning, linear-regression

We have the following loss function:
$$\operatorname{Err}(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(h_w(x_i)-y_i)^2+ λ\|w\|^2$$

1. I need to derive the solution for a polynomial of degree $0$ ($h_w(x)=w_0$) and analyze the solution for $\lambda \rightarrow 0 $ and $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$.
2. I need to do the same for a polynomial of degree $1$ ($h_w(x)=w_0+w_1x$) by computing the derivatives of $w_0$ and $w_1$ and analyze the solution for $\lambda \rightarrow 0 $ and $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$ for each of those derivatives.

Comment: And you also need to show us what you have tried.

Comment: To be honest this is a new subject for me, and I don't really know where to start from